# Android: Showing a Message for less than 2 seconds

Tags: android, notifications, toast, duration

I'd like to display a message or notification for a custom amount of time, in this case for less than 2 seconds.

I've tried two approaches, neither of them was really helpfull:
1. Showing a message via Toast and setting the duration via `LENGTH_SHORT`, which appearently defines a hardcoded duration of 2 seconds. -> Fail
2. creating a `NotificationCompat.Builder` with a `SetTicker` routine and cancel the notification after a certain amount of time. -> The notification (that I do not really need) disappeares after the given time, but the ticker stays unfortunately for a longer duration. :(

```
private void SetNotification(CharSequence aCharSeq)
{
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
    m_RandNotificationID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new    NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setTicker(aCharSeq)
    .setContentTitle(aCharSeq).setContentText(aCharSeq).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sound)
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

  Notification noti = builder.build();

  m_NotMan.notify(m_RandNotificationID, noti);

  new Timer().schedule(CancelAction, 1000L);
}

TimerTask CancelAction = new TimerTask()
{
   public void run()
   {
     m_NotMan.cancel(m_RandNotificationID);
   }
};
```

Any ideas from you would be helpfull. :)

Happy new year

Chris

Comment: Why does the the toast fail?

Comment: You cannot set a custom duration. `SetDuration` only lets you choose between LENGTH_SHORT (2.0 sec) and LENGTH_LONG (3.5 sec?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already mentioned, the duration of a `Toast` can only be set to `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` and `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`. However, it is possible to show a `Toast` shorter than 2 seconds by canceling it earlier, for example after 1 second, using a `Handler`.

```
final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Example Toast",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        toast.cancel();
    }
}, 1000);
```